# Sql Order by Student Grade No

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I want to order my data, I have the following data.

Below is my Data

```
 - 1
 - 1+
 - 1-
 - 2
 - 2+
 - 2-
 - 3
 - 3+
 - 3-
 - 4
 - 4+
 - 4-
```

I would like to order it like this:

```
 - 1+
 - 1
 - 1-
 - 2+
 - 2
 - 2-
 - 3+
 - 3
 - 3-
 - 4+
 - 4
 - 4-
```

I tried this, however I don't get the result I want

```
select * from RatingGrade 
where ScoreCardID=1 
order by GradeNo
```

Comment: Which database, by the way?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6788d/9

Comment: in the spirit of cross compatibility as mentioned by @GolezTrol, probably best to leave the `tags` alone on this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from RatingGrade where ScoreCardID=1 
 order by GradeNo + ','
```

**EDIT**

**HOW THIS WORKS**

Yes, just as people pointed out this is a hacky and tricky solution.

Sometimes just thinking out of the box works. Here I just looked up the ascii chart. `+` is smaller than `-`. So the order of these two is sorted out. All I needed next is a character that falls between these two and that is the `,`. This explains how this works.

Relevent ASCII values at work:

```
43        + (plus)
44        , (comma)
45        - (hyphen)
48-57    numbers 0 to 9.
```

First the first character is compared, which is a number. Since they are same for the set, the second character is compared. This would be either + or - or ,. So they are sorted by ascii order. Since the order is resolved at this stage there is no need to compare the third character.

Comment: Clever but hacky. Hacky, but clever.

Comment: That is some voodoo.  How does that work?  I thought at first it was length but + and - have the same length.  Is it because of the ASCII values?

Comment: when I run this I get the minus, the plus, then the # for all.  such as: 1-,1+,1   etc    maybe my machine is screwed up :>

Comment: Realised that I had missed providing the explaination. Added it to the post now.

Comment: ok my box and [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/339d7/1) same result, out of order

Comment: Can you give a little more reasoning behind this? I would like to see the actual numbers behind the scenes.  I tried using the `ASCII` function to see the values but to no avail.

Comment: @DrewPierce, it should work. The only reason I can think of is that there is a space after number in your sample data. Maybe you declared it as `char(2)`. What happens if you do `... order by RTrim(GradeNo) + ','` ?

Comment: yeah I am over in mysql land, so is my fiddle with your solution. As @GolezTrol said in comments below his Answer, yours will work in mysql with this adjustment in a new [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/339d7/2)

Comment: @TTeeple, I added more explaination. Hope this clears any doubts.

Comment: @PradeepKumar thanks for the clarification!  I was looking at the whole value instead of character position. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, as per comments elsewhere, this works in MySQL if you use CONCAT

Answer (score 2):

You can use substr to get a part of the string. That allows you to sort by the first character first, and a special case of the second character next:

```
select * from  RatingGrade 
where ScoreCardID=1   
order by
  substring(GradeNo, 1, 1),
  case substring(GradeNo, 2, 1)
    when '+' then 'A'
    when '-' then 'C'
    else 'B'
  end
```

-edit- changed `substr` to `substring`, which should work both on MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: I'm gettin yours to work ... nice job ... only yours works I swear

Comment: Mine is probably the least prone to code pages or collations. Also, mine should work on MySQL and SQL Server. However, judging by the score, it seems you've got Pradeem's to work too? That one is quite clever. It adds a `,`, so the values to sort become `1+,` `1,` and `1-,`. The comma is sorted between '+' and '-', which is why it sorts how you want. I'm not sure if that would work on any collation, but if it works for you, it sure is an easy solution.

Comment: I know, I wanted to rejoice upon seeing it, put it here too on the [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/339d7/1)

Comment: That's because it's an SQL Server solution, as is JamesZ's. Mine should be portable. Pradeep's can be made for MySQL by using `CONCAT` to concatenate the `,` to the value.

Comment: well I sprinkled you some points, I like its strategy in other ordering quagmires

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it assumes the number is between 1 and 9:

```
select * from RatingGrade
order by 
  convert(int, left(GradeNo, 1)), 
  case right(GradeNo,1) when '+' then 1 when '-' then 3 else 2 end
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56cdb/1)